# How do you declare instance variables in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I am getting this error and many others due to a problem with the way I am using the 'numerator' and 'denominator' variables: "Inconsistent instance variable specification"

I am new to Objective C, so I am unsure how to resolve this otherwise simple issue.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction: NSObject

-(void)   print;
-(void)   setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void)   setDenominator: (int) d;

@end

@implementation Fraction
{
   int  numerator;
   int  denominator;
}
-(void) print
{
   NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
   numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
   denominator = d;
}

@end

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {
      Fraction  *myFraction;

      myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
      myFraction = [myFraction init];

      [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
      [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

      NSLog (@"The value of myFraction is:");
      [myFraction print];
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your ivars. But replace your 3 lines to create `myFraction` with this one: `Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];`. That's far more typical.

Comment: Are you using CLANG or GCC?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Your code runs fine on my machine (even though you should _never_ `alloc` and `init` on two separate lines).

Comment: GCC is no longer available so it's probably better not to use it.

Comment: GCC does not recognize iVars in the `@implementation` block like CLANG does.  You need to declare them in the interface, or switch compilers.